# Extracting the first two initials of a person's name

Tags: strings, iteration, xslt

I've come up with a hackish approach to get my XSL function to only return the first 2 initials of a person. I think there should be a more efficient way to do this though. The `replace` specifically is what I think I should be able to get rid of, looking through docs though I can't figure out how to correctly iterate with the split.

So 5 examples of my XML:

```
<name>
    <surname>Test I</surname>
    <given-names>Chris</given-names>
</name>
<name>
    <surname>Test II</surname>
    <given-names>Chris Chris</given-names>
</name>
<name>
    <surname>Test III</surname>
    <given-names>Chris Eat Meat</given-names>
</name>
<name>
    <surname>Test IV</surname>
    <given-names>Chris-Eat Meat</given-names>
</name>
<name>
    <surname>Test V</surname>
    <given-names>Chris-Eat-Meat</given-names>
</name>
```

My function call:

```
<xsl:value-of select="pull_it:get_initials(name/given-names/text())"/> <!-- name/given-names -->
```

and my inefficient XSL function:

```
<xsl:function name="pull_it:get_initials">
    <xsl:param name="names"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="
            replace(string-join(
                for $token in tokenize($names,'(-|\s+)')[string-length(.) > 0]
                    return concat(substring($token,1,1),'.'),
                ''), '(\w\.\w?\.?).*', '$1')
                    "/>
</xsl:function>
```

So with the first two XML blocks the expected output/return is:

```
C.
```

and

```
C. C.
```

The remaining three should return (as expected, no `M.` because we only want the first 2 initials)

```
C. E.
```

but I thought there would be a way to stop the iteration. For example my PHP just has:

```
$abbreviated_firstnames = array();
$firstnames = mb_split('(\s+|-)', html_entity_decode($this->firstname,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
$intial_count = 0;
foreach ($firstnames as $firstname) {
    $intial_count++;
    $firstinit = mb_substr($firstname,0,1,'UTF-8');
    if ($firstinit) {
        $abbreviated_firstnames[] = $firstinit . '.';
        if($intial_count >= 2) {
            break; // <---- we got 2 matches stop NOW
        }
    }
}
return implode(' ',$abbreviated_firstnames);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to get rid of the `replace()` by testing the position of the token in an additional predicate.

You should also be able to remove the `string-join()` (unless you don't want spaces between the initials).

You can also remove the `string-length()` test by adjusting the regex for `-`.

New function based on above suggestions:

```
<xsl:function name="pull_it:get_initials">
  <xsl:param name="names"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="
    for $token in tokenize($names,'(-+|\s+)')[2 >= position()]
    return concat(substring($token,1,1),'.')
    "/>
</xsl:function>
```

Complete example (used Saxon-HE 9.5 to test)...

**XML Input** (Added test VI)

```
<doc>
    <name>
        <surname>Test I</surname>
        <given-names>Chris</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Test II</surname>
        <given-names>Chris Chris</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Test III</surname>
        <given-names>Chris Eat Meat</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Test IV</surname>
        <given-names>Chris-Eat Meat</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Test V</surname>
        <given-names>Chris-Eat-Meat</given-names>
    </name>
    <name>
        <surname>Test VI</surname>
        <given-names>Chris---Eat----Meat</given-names>
    </name>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:pull_it="pull_it"
  exclude-result-prefixes="pull_it">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:function name="pull_it:get_initials">
    <xsl:param name="names"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="
      for $token in tokenize($names,'(-+|\s+)')[2 >= position()]
      return concat(substring($token,1,1),'.')
      "/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <initials><xsl:value-of select="pull_it:get_initials(given-names)"/></initials>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <name>
      <surname>Test I</surname>
      <given-names>Chris</given-names>
      <initials>C.</initials>
   </name>
   <name>
      <surname>Test II</surname>
      <given-names>Chris Chris</given-names>
      <initials>C. C.</initials>
   </name>
   <name>
      <surname>Test III</surname>
      <given-names>Chris Eat Meat</given-names>
      <initials>C. E.</initials>
   </name>
   <name>
      <surname>Test IV</surname>
      <given-names>Chris-Eat Meat</given-names>
      <initials>C. E.</initials>
   </name>
   <name>
      <surname>Test V</surname>
      <given-names>Chris-Eat-Meat</given-names>
      <initials>C. E.</initials>
   </name>
   <name>
      <surname>Test V</surname>
      <given-names>Chris---Eat----Meat</given-names>
      <initials>C. E.</initials>
   </name>
</doc>
```